# How do you create an Azure virtual machine that looses state on disconnect?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I would like to create a virtual machine in Azure that is automatically reset to the just-deployed state after a user disconnects.  I can probably do this through creating a backup image and doing a restore after the user logs out with Save-AzureVMImage, but I am wondering if there is any way to set the machine to not save state at all, as used to be the default case in old virtual machines.  The reset state must include the state of the OS, not just applications, so it is bit-for-bit identical (or as practically close as possible) to an initial deployment.  Right now I am re-deploying a new VM manually to achieve this goal.

Is there a way to configure a VM to behave like I want?

If not, is there a way to automate the restore process after a user logs out of the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such feature, but shouldn't be hard to develop something like this using Automation. The first DevOps logic I could think of is:

1. [Create a VM image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image)
2. [Create a Powershell script to destroy the old and deploy a new VM from this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-create-vm-generalized?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json)
3. [Create an Automation account and create a runbook with this script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell)
4. [Use Webhook to trigger the runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks)
5. [Create a Powershell script to verify if no users are logged in](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/17/use-powershell-to-detect-if-a-workstation-is-in-use/) (may need more logic in here)
6. [Improve this script to make an HTTP POST to trigger the runbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)
7. [Assign User Logoff Script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753583(v=ws.11).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396)

Probably you could skip step 5 tho and step 2 actually needs to be done after step 7 because you need the script configured in the VM before snapshot.

Comment: It looks like your answer was about as easy at it gets on Azure.  Thank you!  I ended up switching providers which saved a lot of money and had the features I wanted built-in (paperspace.com).